# Aurelia @bindable *Changed calls on initialisation

Tags: aurelia

I'm finding that when I define a @bindable property, and a propertyChanged handler for it, it sometimes gets called before the custom component's bind() method and sometimes doesn't.

https://gist.run/?id=d7d9e7c7080f581f8e81b888268a2f11

In several places, I'm using these propertyChanged handler on one property to trigger updates to another, in situations where a @computedFrom isn't appropriate, as the second value is a complex calculation that I don't want called multiple times.

For now, I'm having to do the following:

```
@bindable propOne;
@bindable propTwo;

propOneChanged(newVal) {
  propTwo = "something complex " + newVal;
}

bind() {
**  propOneChanged(propOne);**
}
```

Is there any better way to do this (e.g. something in the @bindable decorator) so that I don't need to manually 'prime' the property in the bind()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any better way to do this (e.g. something in the @bindable decorator) so that I don't need to manually 'prime' the property in the bind()?

No.

If you don't have a `bind()` method, then Aurelia will call your change handlers during `bind()`. Unless you've got specific things you need to do (besides priming your bindables), **remove the bind() method**. Then you don't need to worry about this.

If you *do* have a `bind()` method, then that's the correct place for you to invoke your change handlers.

Also, I get the impression you're not entirely sure how bindables work.

Simply put: a `@bindable` decorator tells the Aurelia framework to wrap that property in a `get` + `set` method (this happens when the component is loaded, way before its lifecycle).

The `set` method invokes the change handler whenever it receives a value that's different from the current value - when you assign a value to a `bindable`, the change handler is invoked, regardless of whether the component is bound, even if it's not a ViewModel.

So to address your comment:

> it sometimes gets called before the custom component's bind() method and sometimes doesn't.

It will be called before the custom component's bind() method *if and only if* you assign some value to it before the custom component's bind(). For example, in the constructor or in the property initializer.

Answer (score 0):

the xyChanged protoype is `xyChanged(newValue, oldValue)`. To prevent unwanted behaviour i'm always doing

```
if(oldvalue === null) return;
```

(which is null directly after bind()). If you use async model-requests its in most cases meaningfull to do a null check in your view

```
<div if.bind="model.data">...</div>
```

Comment: Correct about the async requests, but doing it like that in your view can make an app very brittle if it's large and complex. Easier to either load data during `activate()`, or if it has to happen during `bind()` simply use a compositionTransaction.
Btw, `oldValue` will always be `undefined` on the first change (rather than `null`), so that check doesn't do anything in that scenario.